# form tag doesn't render in partial view with jquery dialog. mvc3 asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i have a partial view "CreateJobLine.cshtml" that contains a form. this form when rendered using @Html.Action method creates the form fields without the form tag. i used the Html.BeginForm as well as hard coded the form (below), but in both situation its not generating the  tag. I am also using jqueryui's dialog widget to display the form.

---Partial View    ---

```
//filename: CreateJobLine.cshtml
@model Recruitment.Models.JobLine
@if(false){
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
<div id="addnewjoblinediv">
<form id="createjoblineform" action="@Url.Action("CreateJobLine")" method="post">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>JobLine</legend>
        @Html.Hidden("job_id", Model.JobId)
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TimeSpent)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TimeSpent)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TimeSpent)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.JobId)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JobId)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>   
</div>
```

In the edit view, I have Html.Action call to load the partial view.

---Edit View---

```
//filename Edit.cshtml
... 
@Html.Action("CreateJobLine", "Job", new { job_id = Model.Job.JobId})

    <a id="addnewjoblinelink" href="#">Add New JobLine</a>

</fieldset>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("div#addnewjoblinediv").dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal:true, width:550, title:"Add New JobLine"});

        $("a#addnewjoblinelink").click(function () {
            $("div#addnewjoblinediv").dialog("open");
        }
        );
    }
    );

</script>
```

Here is the controller
---Job Controller---

```
//JobController.cs
...
[HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult CreateJobLine(int job_id)
    {
        var jobline = new JobLine();
        jobline.JobId = job_id;
        jobline.TimeSpent = 0;
        return PartialView(jobline);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateJobLine(JobLine jobline)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.JobLines.Add(jobline);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = jobline.JobId });
    }
  ...
```

call to /Job/CreateJobLine/5 gets the form content with all the form elements, but the form tag itself is missing. I want to get that form action be set to /Job/CreateJobLine post method so that I can create a JobLine.

Thank you.

Comment: I realized my mistake, this was a case of nested form. the child form was not being rendered correctly ie it was missing the form tag. The form code is still there in source of the webpage. but the browser is not rendering the form.
Now I have to figure out how to get by without having nested forms.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is @Html.Action.  I believe it's simpler and closer to what you want to just render a partial view like this:

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("CreateJobLine", new MvcApplication1.Models.JobLine { JobId = 10 }); }
```

I say that because when I use RenderPartial like I would normally do, the form is rendered correctly inside the dialog (all the rest of the code is how you posted it).  I can't use Html.Action with the code you posted (probably because you omitted something else), so that indicates to me your problem is around that method.  Good luck.